# Need to run the code generated by blockly on Android

Tags: android, blockly

I have integrated Blockly on Android.

Using the block editor, I can make a code block. On running it, it gives JavaScript code as output.

I'm running the code generated by blockly on the Android app itself in a WebView and getting an output which I need to pass via bluetooth.

So how do I pass the output via bluetooth that uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) ?

Comment: you want to run JS code? You can try using WebView for that.

Comment: yes. i can use webview to run the JS code. How do I send the output via bluetooth ? Edited the question

Comment: first you need to get the `output` from WebView, and then send that data via Bluetooth. That are 2 separate tasks/problems. Which you don't know how to solve?

Comment: How to send via bluetooth. I have problem in that. I have to use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) to pass the bluetooth data.

Comment: ok, there are a lot of ways to send data via Bluetooth. First you should specify *where* you want to send it. To which device? Does it have any special protocol on top of general Bluetooth, etc.

Comment: its a nordic development board (PCA10040) i want the send the data to. this one - https://www.keil.com/boards2/nordicsemiconductors/nrf52pca10040/

Comment: then it completely depends on the board program. I am using Nordic prints in my project too, and our hardware developers completely control the way it should communicate via bluetooth

Comment: so how are you sending the output generated by Javascript on Android via bluetooth ? Just need some pinters to proceede further

Comment: there is no matter how it was generated since I doubt it is a string. I don't use libraries, I send it via Bluetooth Socket

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135653/discussion-between-gissipi-453-and-vlad-matvienko).